# How do artists create non linear abstract interpolated gradients images

Tags: objective-c, swift, metal

I've seen many versions of multicolored gradient like images, that are both non linear and heavily stylized. Usually in the form of layered blob like shapes.

My guess as to how they achieve this effect is

1. drawing intersecting blob like shapes
2. masking gradients on the shapes
3. interpolating the colors on the image.

However as you'll notice by the distinct lines in the image the interpolated effect only appears in certain regions of the image. This effect is what I would like to achieve in metal.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

One approach is to draw your solid colors and then apply a zoom or motion blur CoreImage filter to achieve the effect of a gradient, leaving some detail by where you place the center (for zoom) or the angle you set (for motion).

Here's an example of a before and a couple afters. The original image in this case is drawn with 2D function plotting but you could easily use a static input image/video-frame, draw an image with filled bezier paths, etc.

[image: original image with three solid colors]

The second image uses a CIZoomBlur, input center pt just off image center at (240, 220), with amount set to 134.9.

[image: image with CIZoomBlur image applied]

The CIMotionBlur filter also produces some interesting gradient effects. Here's the same input image, with CIMotionBlur inputRadius 57.6 and inputAngle -0.415.

[image: image with CIMotionBlur filter applied]

I think this could achieve what you're after providing you set up the original solid-color image as you like and are able to figure out optimal settings for the filters (angle, center pt etc.).

Comment: This is very close, but I'm not entirely sure this is it. The effect I'm after is the same found in the Apple Music app lyrics view, where it shows the same effect but "animated". CIFilters are only applicable to static images. Unless you think they are doing a stop motion like effect? Not sure if that'd be performant. Thoughts?

Comment: It is possible to "animate" the settings of an CIFilter image, i.e. to gradually change the inputCenter of a zoom blur and the direction of a motion blur, to coordinate with generated path-drawing for a moving image. Also, using both zoom and motion together could make the effects look even more 'nonlinear'. I think the filters are going to be way more performant than doing something that's more of a true calculated gradient across a field, but you could also experiment with NSGradient in arbitrary bezier paths - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsgradient

Comment: Hi @Stefan Did you get any progress? I'm also trying to acheive the same animation effect. Please let me know.

Comment: @MasterAgentX I found the method listed above great for generating images but Core Image as the name would imply is only able to do just that. The animated effect is likely achieved through a GPU shader. The effect is a gradient mesh with interpolated colors. I found this video to be a good starter : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c-5MD03NUMw&t=608s  Unfortunately, I haven't gotten the time to sit down and really dive deep into this. I will eventually though and will update this thread accordingly. Let me know if you have any luck.